# Variable constraints on user input problem

Tags: javascript, variables, range

I've been struggling with the following task for hours now:
Convert miles per gallon to km per 100 liters in JS. I keep failing one of the unit tests.

My code:

```
let milesPerGallon = Number(gets());
// I have to use gets() to accept user input and print() instead of console.log()
let converter = 100 / ((milesPerGallon * 1.6) / 4.54);
print(Math.floor(converter) + ' liters per 100 km');
```

I am failing the following constraints:

1 <= milesPerGallon <= 100

I have tried `Math.min(Number(gets()), 100)` in order to avoid a values above range but it doesn't work.

This is supposed to be at beginner level btw, so I am kind of hoping to find a simple solution - no added functions or anything.

Comment: What is it expecting you to do if entered input is out of range?

Comment: step 1: verify that gets() is a number, which you'll want to do using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), not `Number`, and then making sure that `isNaN(milesPerGallon)` is false. Then, _set_ the value to 1 if it's less than 1, and _set_ it to 100 if it's over 100.

Comment: Okay, parseFloat worked like a charm, dude. Thanks a lot. The real question is: why is Number not the way to go here? What is the difference between parseFloat and Number in JS?